# Alt+Arrow key bindings not working in xfce4-terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xfce4-terminal

In my shell I can move around in a long command line by jumping to the previous or next word delimiter by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>, using <kbd>Esc</kbd> as a prefix to replace the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.  The key bindings are likely the following:

```
$ bindkey | grep -a -- -word
(...)
"^[^[[D"       -> backward-word
"^[^[[C"       -> forward-word
(...)
```

However, when I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> key combination the special code is not recognised and two letters "3D" printed:

```
$echo longcommand longcommand longcommand longcommand
(pressing at the end of the line at this point)
$echo longcommand longcommand longcommand longcommand3D
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will give "3C".

`xev` shows the same KeyPress event for <kbd>←</kbd> key the with and without <kbd>Alt</kbd> (using left Alt here).

**How can I get the <kbd>Alt</kbd> variants to work when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> prefix variants already work?**

This happens in `xfce4-terminal`, in `xterm` the key combination works.

Answer (score 1):

xfce4-terminal uses the vte library for all of the relevant features.  In this case, that would be the *meta* feature in xterm (see [**`altIsNotMeta`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:altIsNotMeta) and [**`altSendsEscape`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:altSendsEscape), as well as [**`metaSendsEscape`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:metaSendsEscape)).  vte doesn't implement that.  If it did, it (to imitate xterm properly) it should also recognize an escape sequence for switching meta mode off/on.  It doesn't do that, either.

Since VTE is undocumented, you have to read its [*source-code*](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte) to gain an understanding of its features.

Checking my reading of the source-code with xfce4-terminal 0.8.9.2 and vte 0.62.1, the latter partially implements this sequence ([private mode 1036](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-1-0-3-6.1F81)), in [vte.cc](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/src/vte.cc#L4950):

```
 Ps = 1 0 3 6  ⇒  Send ESC   when Meta modifies a key, xterm.
      This enables the metaSendsEscape resource.
```

but it omits the treatment of special keys (which your question is about).  A comment before that block says

```
/* If we got normal characters, send them to the child. */
```

The special keys use the modifiers as derived in [`widget.cc`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/src/widget.cc#L374):

```
    /* Read the modifiers. See bug #663779 for more information on why we do this. */
    auto mods = GdkModifierType{};
    if (!gdk_event_get_state(event, &mods))
            return 0;

    #if 1
    /* HACK! Treat META as ALT; see bug #663779. */
    if (mods & GDK_META_MASK)
            mods = GdkModifierType(mods | GDK_MOD1_MASK);
    #endif
```

Bug report [#663779](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663779) goes into some detail about the way the vte developers hard-coded part of xterm's behavior in this area .  The part that they're talking about is for special keys (such as ***Alt+arrow***, combined with alt or meta).  That appears to be this chunk, in [`vte.cc`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/src/vte.cc#L4892):

```
        _vte_keymap_map(keyval, m_modifiers,
                                    m_modes_private.DEC_APPLICATION_CURSOR_KEYS(),
                                    m_modes_private.DEC_APPLICATION_KEYPAD(),
                &normal,
                &normal_length);
        /* If we found something this way, suppress
         * escape-on-alt. */
                    if (normal != NULL && normal_length > 0) {
            suppress_alt_esc = TRUE;
        }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that's pretty detailed, will need to put in some work to understand that all. TL;DR: It won't work unless source code is changed? (No config options?!)